# Shared column between FK and PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two tables, A and B (not defined by me, inherited from old legacy software), with the following structure:

```
A: PK (idA, ente),

B: PK(idB, ente), FK(idA, ente) --> A
```

I need to use @IdClass/@Id, rather than @Embeddeble/@EmbeddebleId, because @GeneratedValue on id columns.

I'd like to insert a new couple of rows this way:

```
A a = new A();
a.setEnte('E1');
a = repA.save(a);

B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
b = repB.save(b);
```

I use Spring Data JPA's repositories class. My best try, was:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@IdClass(BPK.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B  implements Serializable{
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idA", referencedColumnName="idA", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="ente", referencedColumnName="ente", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
        })
    private A a;

    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "incrementGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="incrementGenerator")
    @Column(name = "idB", columnDefinition = "int(10)", nullable = false)
    private Integer idB;

    @Id
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false, length=6)
    private String ente;
}


@Getter
@ToString
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@IdClass(APK.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "incrementGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="incrementGenerator")
    @Column(name = "idA", columnDefinition = "int(10)", nullable = false)
    private Integer idA;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ente", columnDefinition = "char(6)", nullable = false)
    public String ente;
}
```

This solution doesn't work, because *idA* and *ente* are not inserted in save(b) instruction. If I change insertable=true in the `@ManyToOne` lines, there will be error on ente field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about removing `insertable = false` from `B#ente`?

Comment: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : B.idA

Comment: Well, then set the property to a non-null value. What's the problem?

Comment: It is not possible to proceed as you say, or rather, it is a workaround. The problem is the column that should be inherited from the FK: B.a#idA. The value is generated whem 'a' is instanceated, so it's not null. On b.setA(a); 'a' has its PK correctly set.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about here. If you need help, create a test case (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that shows what you are trying to do and how it fails.

Comment: What you are proposing (correct me if I am wrong) is to proceed according to this pattern
A a = new A();
a.setEnte('E1');
a = repA.save(a);

B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
b.setEnte(a.getEnte());
b = repB.save(b);

This is a workaround. It works, but it's a workaround.

Comment: Your `b.setA()` method could also set this automatically. Not sure if I'd call this a bug though. I think the model is a bit broken, but please create a test case and JIRA issue for others to judge that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your b.setA() method could also set this automatically

Thanks to Christian Beikov's suggestion, I found an acceptable solution to the problem.
Why it should not infer data directly from the entities is not clear to me.

However, the solution is to force the missing data to be set before persisting using @PrePersist.

The model for B becomes:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@IdClass(BPK.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B  implements Serializable{
    
        @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idA", referencedColumnName="idA", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="ente", referencedColumnName="ente", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
        })
    private A a;

    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "incrementGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="incrementGenerator")
    @Column(name = "idB", columnDefinition = "int(10)", nullable = false)
    private Integer idB;

    @Id
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false, length=6)
    private String ente;
    
//New lines (In the real code I used getters, of course) <--
    @Column(name = "idA", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int(10)")
    private Integer idA;

    @PrePersist
    private void init() {
        this.ente = a.ente;
        this.idA= a.idA;
    }
}
```